# Download PDF via Post HTTP Request in Python using Request (not GET)

Tags: python-3.x, http, post, python-requests

My problem is slightly different from many others. I am doing a POST with a response of a download PDF (not text) and you can see the stack trace below.  I can not find any answers on this.

```
base_url = "https://homeland.my.salesforce.com"
action = base_url + "/sfc/p/#1I000003o0lm/a/8W000001Dmtq/GT9FLcwrLX3QQjVDLCEonLxmCi6nG4VqCUJzDyK80GU"

qdata = {"compositePageName",
        "1I000003o0lm/a/8W000001Dmtq/GT9FLcwrLX3QQjVDLCEonLxmCi6nG4VqCUJzDyK80GU" }


#req = requests.post(url=action, data=qdata)
req = requests.post(url=action, stream=True, data=qdata)

# blows up on above method with message
```

C:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\PycharmProjects\02_getproperty\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 50548 --file C:/Users/Quentin_Sarafinchan/PycharmProjects/02_getproperty/main.py index.html --debug
Connected to pydev debugger (build 212.5457.59)
debug - turned on
[https://homeland.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/1I000003o0lm/a/8W000001Dmtq/GT9FLcwrLX3QQjVDLCEonLxmCi6nG4VqCUJzDyK80GU"](https://homeland.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/1I000003o0lm/a/8W000001Dmtq/GT9FLcwrLX3QQjVDLCEonLxmCi6nG4VqCUJzDyK80GU%22)
style="mso-style-priority:100 !important;text-decoration:none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;
mso-line-height-rule:exactly;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;border-style:solid;border-color:#BB9A65;border-width:10px 15px;display:inline-block;background:#BB9A65;border-radius:0px;
font-family:'open sans', 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;line-height:17px;width:auto
text-align:center" target="_blank">
URL:  https://homeland.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/1I000003o0lm/a/8W000001Dmtq/GT9FLcwrLX3QQjVDLCEonLxmCi6nG4VqCUJzDyK80GU
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1001, in send
self.sock.sendall(data)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1201, in sendall
with memoryview(data) as view, view.cast("B") as byte_view:
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\PycharmProjects\02_getproperty\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\PycharmProjects\02_getproperty\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\PycharmProjects\02_getproperty\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\PycharmProjects\02_getproperty\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
resp = conn.urlopen(
File "C:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\PycharmProjects\02_getproperty\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
httplib_response = self._make_request(
File "C:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\PycharmProjects\02_getproperty\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
File "C:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\PycharmProjects\02_getproperty\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 239, in request
super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1280, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1079, in _send_output
self.send(chunk)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1005, in send
self.sock.sendall(d)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1201, in sendall
with memoryview(data) as view, view.cast("B") as byte_view:
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
python-BaseException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use byte array

```
#qdata = {"compositePageName",
#        "1I00EonLxmCi6nG4VqCUJzDyK80GU" }
nm = "compositePageName"
val = "LxmCi6nG4VqCUJzDyK80GU"
s = nm + "=" + val

qdata = bytearray(s, 'utf-8')
mv = memoryview(qdata)
req = requests.post(url=action, stream=True, data=mv)
```